# Find equations of two planes given their intersection line in vector form and their two normals

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Assume I have points $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ space.

So therefore I have equation of the line in $\mathbb R^3$ in the vector form: $r = r_1 + \lambda u$, where $u$ is directional unit vector and $r_1$ is radius-vector of point $P_1$.

I also have two normals for the planes that are intersect each other: $\vec {n_{lat}}$ and $\vec{n_{lon}}$.

Is it possible to derive equations of these two planes in general form?

e.g:

$f(x,y,z) = a_1x + b_1y + c_1z + d_1$

$g(x,y,z) = a_2x + b_2y + c_2z + d_2$

Comment: You only need one of the points if both planes go through it. Given a point P and a normal n then the plane is $r.n = P.n$ where $r = (x, y, z)$.

Comment: Yes, true, silly question really, thanks for the help!